# Base64 Failed to Decode String to Byte Array

Tags: java, string, base64, byte, lzw

I tried to decode a `string` to byte array using `Base64`. But it returned `null`. Here is the code:

```
    LZW lzw = new LZW();
    String enkripEmbedFileString = Base64.encode(byteFile);
    List<Short> compressed = lzw.compress(enkripEmbedFileString);

    String kompress = "";
    Iterator<Short> compressIterator = compressed.iterator();
    while (compressIterator.hasNext()) {
        String sch = compressIterator.next().toString();
        int in = Integer.parseInt(sch);
        char ch = (char) in;
        kompress = kompress + ch;
    }

    byteFile = Base64.decode(kompress);
```

I call "byteFile" variable at the last row in a code below this code and it throw `NullPointerException`.
I have check the "kompress" variable and it's not null. It contains a `string`.

All you need to know is, with that code I compress a string with LZW which require String for parameter and returns `List<Short>`. And, I convert the `List<Short>` to a String with a loop that you can see.

The problem is, why Base64 failed to convert `String` to `byte[]`, after that String modified with LZW?

Whereas, if I decompress the String first and than return the decompressed String to be converted with Base64 to byte[], has no problem. It works. Here is the code which works:

```
    //LZW Compress      
    LZW lzw = new LZW();
    String enkripEmbedFileString = Base64.encode(byteFile);
    List<Short> compressed = lzw.compress(enkripEmbedFileString);

    String kompress = "";
    Iterator<Short> compressIterator = compressed.iterator();
    while (compressIterator.hasNext()) {
        String sch = compressIterator.next().toString();
        int in = Integer.parseInt(sch);
        char ch = (char) in;
        kompress = kompress + ch;
    }

    //Decompress        
    List<Short> kompressback = back(kompress);
    String decompressed = decompress(kompressback);

    byteFile = Base64.decode(decompressed);
```

Please, give me an explanation. Where is my fault?

Comment: Have you examined (i.e. printed out) the string being input to the Base64 decoder? Is it valid Base64?

Comment: Did you mean, Base64 only can decode a String which is encoded with Base64 to?

Comment: That would be logical, yes.  What would expect to be the result of trying to apply Base64 _decode_ to a string that wasn't the output of a previous Base64 _encode_? That would make no sense.

Comment: So, of course my code return null because the String has modified with LZW and not compatible for Base64 again?

Comment: Ok thank you so much @Jim Garrison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base64 *decode* can be applied only to strings that contain Base64 *encoded* data.  Since you encode and then compress, the result is not Base64.  You proved it yourself when you saw that uncompressing the data first allowed you to then decode the Base64 string.